# React Native build failed - (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')

Tags: react-native, apple-m1

I am using Mac M1, trying to run React Native on IOS Simulator and I got this error:

```
CompileC /Users/jack/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sample-gnrhtdrpdsucuifckqcsppcsfdbn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SysUio.o /Users/jack/React\ Native/sample/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/SysUio.cpp normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
```

Any solution to solve this?

Comment: Which version of React Native you're using? They added support for M1 in 0.66.0 I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/facebook/folly/issues/1670
This link had the solution for me, ensure that your project path doesn't have any spaces within it. I have an M1 Pro and it worked.

Comment: Jack Venevankham, why did you not accept my answer as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.
What I did is, check the project folder path and then realised space contain in one folder.

1. solution (1). remove the space and re open the project and run.
2. solution (2). create new project without spaces in folder path.

> Blockquote

Ex: User/My Project/ABC need to change into User/MyProject/ABC

My recommendation is solution 2